# How do you called a code that covers everything?

Tags: language-agnostic

I wondered how you call a code that covers every possibility a User can imagine. I mean, like a code where every Bug is tested out and the user can think of "I wonder if I can do this" and he actually can, or "I wonder if the Programmer thought about that" and the programmer did...
Is it called a complete code, or a perfect code? Is there a technical term for it?

Comment: That is called "Programming" :)

Comment: Is it that simple? My programming teacher always talks about usability, ergonomics, and "covering all options", so I thought there would be a technical term?

Comment: There is no such thing as code that covers every possibility and that has no bugs whatsoever, at least after you get beyond "hello world".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [The Principle of Least Astonishment](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/us-cranky10/index.html).

Of course it's impossible to build a perfect interface or write perfect code, so there are never any surprises, but you can try to get as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Magic.** At least from the user's perspective, according to [Arthur C. Clarke's third law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws):

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.

From the <strike>magician's</strike> programmer's point of view, it's impossible to cover every possibility imaginable (see [Halting Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) for example). However, by following good coding conventions, such as the one @PatrickMcElhaney mentions, you can get close to code that "covers everything."

One method I'd like to add is **[unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)**: if you write unit tests with inputs that a user may enter, you'll be one step closer to being sure you've "covered everything."